# Multiple text conditions in IF statement in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I need to do this: If `D`2 equals "yes" and `E2` equals "no" then return "ok" in `F2.
I am having trouble with checking 2 different cells for text as part of an if statement. How can I do this or something with similar results?

Answer (score 1):

try in F2:

```
=IF(AND(D2="yes"; E2="no"); "ok"; "not ok")
```

based on docs: [AND()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9)

otherwise you could nest if checks of course *(look at other answer)*

Answer (score 0):

You could try and nest the if-statements:

```
=IF(D2="yes";(IF(E2="no";"OK";"");"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AND(condition1,condition2)` or nested `IF`'s:

`=IF(AND(D2="yes",E2="no"),"ok","not ok")`

`=IF(D2<>"yes","not ok",IF(E2="no","ok","not ok"))`